# How to read child XML using XPath in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, soap, xml-parsing

The XML file is as :

[Xml File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdCHH.png)

Code I have written:

List queryXmlUsingXpathAndReturnList(String xml, String xpathExpression) {

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()

DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder()

Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize()

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()

NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(xpathExpression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)

List returnElements = new ArrayList<>()

nodeList.each { n ->

returnElements.add(n.getTextContent())

}

When I am passing the xpath as:

/Envelope/Body/CommandResponseData/OperationResult/Operation/ParameterList/ListParameter/StringElement

It returns all the values.
But I want to return only the ListParameter values whose  name="PackageTypeList".

For that I am using the xpath as:

/Envelope/Body/CommandResponseData/OperationResult/Operation/ParameterList/ListParameter[@name='PackageTypeList']/StringElement

But it returns list as null.

Comment: Pictures are useless. Please edit your post and add your XML as a text.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you miss "CommandResult" between "CommandResponseData" and "OperationResult" in your XPath-Expression.

Comment: It seems wrongly I pasted it.
My xpath is:
/Envelope/Body/CommandResponseData/CommandResult/OperationResult/Operation/ParameterList/ListParameter[@name='PackageList']/StringElement
Still getting null response.
If I will remove [@name='PackageList'] , I am getting all the values, but as I mentioned I need specific data whose name=PackageList.